# How is GetLinkById() supposed to work in Gazebo 1.3?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

After I upgraded to Gazebo 1.3 (from 1.2.5) I noticed the **`model->GetLink()`** function has changed. It does not overload anymore with the (string) **`link_name`** or with the (unsigned int) **`id`** arguments.


 Now there are two functions **`GetLink(string link_name)`** and **`GetLinkByID(unsigned int _id)`**.
However the later **`GetLinkById()`** it doesn't work.

Is it a bug? Or am I not using it right, I used it for example with values 0 or 1 (0 being until now the first link of the model).

Code example:
`this->model->GetLinkById(0)->GetName().c_str()`

The error I get:

```
gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::physics::Link]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

Thanks, Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1212/how-is-getlinkbyid()-supposed-to-work-in-gazebo-1.3?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The ID of a link is a unique integer that is assigned when the Link is instantiated. The ID is primarily used for internal purposes.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-05**:
Here is a pull request to "fix" this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/271/remove-doxygen-processing-of-some-internal/diff

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-05**:
Here is a pull request to "fix" this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/271/remove-doxygen-processing-of-some-internal/diff